# How do I reset the viewport lens angle?

Tags: interface

I pressed a button and I cant seem to get back to the normal perspective view, everything looks like it's being seen from a telescope. Orthographic view is still displayed normally but perspective view looks like this.

[image]

How can I revert this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the View section of the N panel in 3d view, change the Lens value back to 35. it's probably at 3 or something

[image]

Comment: How did you record this hi-speed gif?

Comment: used the built-in screencast, then loaded the images as layers in GIMP, cropped an area, added some extra frame timing to the last frame, then saved as a GIF/animation.

Answer (score 1):

You could try if one or more of the following shortcuts help:

- ESC (cancel any actions)
- Numpad 5 (switch orthogonal / perspective view)
- q (quit game engine)
- Numpad 1 (front view)

I don't know what your view actually is, but probably they help.

Comment: I'm am on the user perspective view, but some how the perspective view has a high focal length and i don't know where to reduce it